# Extract each value of a single property from an array of objects in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to create a new object iterating over an array of objects which initially looks like this:

```
startObj = [{'prop': true}, {'prop': false}];
```

I would like the result to be:

```
endObj = {0: true, 1: false}
```

I was thinking to use `$.each` but then I don't know how to proceed from here. Any hints?

```
$.each([{'prop': true}, {'prop': false}], function (i, o) {
    var newObj;
    // the new object should look like this
    // newObj = {0: true, 1: false}
});
```

Comment: Your question asks for the result to be an object with properties `0`, `1` etc, however this looks a lot like an array - and most answers give you back an array not an object. What is it you actually want back?

Comment: This is not a jQuery object, it's a simple array...

Comment: @FelixKling - yes, but OP is using jquery `.each` to iterate over it. And why not? If you're using jQuery you're free to use `each` to iterate it.

Comment: @Jamiec: I'm not saying that one cannot use jQuery for this. OP originally wrote "I have this jQuery object" and I just wanted to clarify that it is a normal array of objects. It's not related to jQuery at all and using jQuery does not make everything a "jQuery object" or "jQuery array". That's all :)

Comment: @FelixKling - Ah I C. Didnt see (or perhaps didnt notice) the original wording.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
var newObj = {};
$.each([{'prop': true}, {'prop': false}], function (i, o) {
    newObj[i] = o.prop;
});
```

Live example: http://jsfiddle.net/8X48q/

Answer (score 12):

Here's a one-liner.

```
var newObj = $.map(oldObj, function(val) { return val.prop; });
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/V9gej/).

If the OP really wants an object (or rather, doesn't want an array)...

```
var newObj = $.extend({}, $.map(oldObj, function(val) { return val.prop; }));
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8wYJG/).

Comment: +1 for the simplest solution if the OP actually wants an array rather than an object which pretends to be an array.

Comment: @Jamiec Added the alternative if the OP really wants an object.

Comment: This is not a one-liner if you have automatic code-formatting.

Answer (score 1):

First off, that's just native JS, there's no jQuery needed here.

```
var startObj = [{'prop': true}, {'prop': false}],
    endObj = [], // This could also be {} if you want but if you just have an array in startObj, it doesn't make much sense
     i = 0,
     i_max = startObj.length;

for (i; i < i_max; i++) {
    endObj.push( startObj[i].prop );
    // if you changed endObj to be {} then use the following line instead of the one above
    // endObj[i] = startObj[i].prop;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're not really creating an object here, but an array:

```
var newObj = [];//array
$.each([{'prop': true}, {'prop': false}], function (i, o)
{
    newObj[i] = o.prop
});
```

But to avoid globals, you might want to use a IIFE:

```
var newObj = (function()
{//takes any amount of objects as argument
    var returnArray = [];
    var argumentsToArray = Array.prototype.slice.apply(arguments,[0]);//create array of objects passed
    $.each(argumentsToArray, function (i, o)
    {
        returnArray[i] = o.prop
    });
    return returnArray;//is assigned to newObj
})({'prop': true}, {'prop': false});//1 obj, 2, 3, 4, 5... doesn't matter
```

Comment: How does the first snippet have globals that the second avoids? It appears to be exactly the same to me, why do you make it so complicated?

Comment: It's not really globals in this case, but there's more ways you can go with an IIFE in a case like this: wrap it in a callable function, and pass a property name/property names, pass as many object as you like,... this snippet can't do those things yet, sure, but it won't require that much effort to implement new features this way (IMO)

Comment: Ok... it sounded like the first snippet had a major drawback which you tried to compensate in the second snippet. Btw, I don't think you need to convert `arguments` into a proper array, I think jQuery can handle array-like objects properly.

Comment: @FelixKling: I haven't tested the code, I wasn't entirely sure so I went for the safer route... And maybe someone might see this and discover `arguments` isn't an array, so I figured best to include that line. Just tested in console, arguments is processed just fine

Answer (score -3):

```
var obj = "{";
$.each([{'prop': true}, {'prop': false}], function (index, o) {
    obj += '"' + index  + '":'  + o.prop + ",";
});
var newObj = obj.substring(0, obj.length - 1);
newObj += "}";
console.log(newObj);
console.log($.parseJSON(newObj));
​
```

Comment: I would say *too dirty to post* ;)

Comment: Yup its dirty. But its a solution. So It can take place. :)

Comment: Uh... please **never ever** do something like this... I'm actually inclined to downvote this, since it is not useful IMO.

Comment: sure. Knowledge is worth sharing. I don't know the other solution. Now I also gained knowledge from this. Thanks

Comment: I don't get this solution - why would you *ever* want to do this by string-mashing +parsing that string?

Comment: @Jamiec Who said you to judge the answer of other. If this is irrelevant answer you can point it out, if this don't give you desire output you can mark it wrong. But if this is solution this mean its a solution.

Comment: @ZahidRiaz - This place is akin to a democracy, that is to say that I am entirely entitled to a) an opinion on an answer and b) to express that opinion for the purpose of the original questioner, as well as future visitors of the site. This answer may well give the requested result, but it does so in the **worst possible way**.

Comment: agreed. No problem with that. Because You gained the privileges. and agreed to that its a worst possible way.